# AngularJS orderBy date filter not working using Firebase

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm using Firebase to store my data and I am aware that Firebase stores data as objects and not arrays. I have fixed that problem and have other filters working, but when I try to use "orderBy: 'date'" in my ng-repeat, it does not work. Here is the markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events | limitTo:10 | filter:tfilter | orderBy: 'date'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <h4>{{event.date | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do'}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <h4>{{event.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I've also tried using orderBy: 'event.date', but this did not work either. Anyone know the solution?

Comment: What is getting outputted instead? Do you have an example available?

Comment: If `events` is returned directly from `$firebase(xxx)`, then the type of the events is just an dictionary. You need to flatten it as an array and the filter will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -- super easy. In my mainSvc, I was returning objects instead of array. Where array is below was object.

```
angular.module("zenCityApp")
.factory("mainSvc", function ($rootScope, $log, $firebase) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://zencity.firebaseio.com/events");

  var sync = $firebase(ref);

  var getEvents = function() {
    return sync.$asArray();

  };

  var addEvent = function (singleEvent) {
    ref.push(singleEvent);
  };

  return {
    getEvents: getEvents,
    addEvent: addEvent
  }

});
```